# CodenameOne ImageViewer blocks scroll

Tags: codenameone

I have a form with an ImageViewer on it and some text fields underneath. The form is set to be scrollableY, but it can't be scrolled by touching anywhere inside the ImageViewer. When the device is in landscape however, the image takes up the whole screen and the user can no longer scroll the form down. Is it possible to set anything on the ImageViewer to "listen" for scrolling or would I be best to just use a normal Image instead. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `ImageViewer` in a scrollable `Container`. We recommend placing it in the center of a `BorderLayout` which implicitly disables scrolling.

The `ImageViewer` supports panning/zooming which negates the idea of scrolling. I'm guessing that what you really want is [ScaleImageLabel](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/ScaleImageLabel.html).